# Rename file in Fortran 77

Tags: file, fortran, rename

Is there a way to rename a file in fortran 77? such as:

```
RENAME(old name, new name)
```

or something like:

```
call system("rename" // trim(old name) // " " // trim(new name))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you nailed it with the first one:

```
CALL RENAME('oldname','newname')
```

More [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rename_a_file).  And [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RENAME.html#RENAME).

Comment: A possibly more relevant link than Rosetta code would be the [gcc doc page on RENAME](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RENAME.html#RENAME).

Comment: Added that doc page link to the answer.

Comment: Note that RENAME is not a standard Fortran intrinsic routine. It is commonly available in many implementations as an extension, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [modFileSys](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/modfilesys) library for that. In contrast to non-standard compiler extensions, it can be compiled with any Fortran 2003 compiler and can be used an all POSIX compatible systems. You could also check for errors, if needed:

```
program test
  use libmodfilesys_module
  implicit none

  integer :: error

  ! Renaming with error handling
  call rename("old.dat", "new.dat", error=error)
  if (error /= 0) then
    print *, "Error happened"
  end if

  ! Renaming without explicit error handling, stops the program
  ! if error happens.
  call rename("old2.dat", "new2.dat")

end program test
```