# How do I edit the existing file in fortran and export it to the same file

Tags: fortran

I am trying to exchange some characters in my input file.
My code is working properly if I export the data to a new file.
However, I can not export my changes to the same file. After first 2 line, it does not export the data correctly. Do you have any suggestions for me?

This is my data that I need to change (I need to remove the % symbols)

test.su2:

```
%file
%
%
%
4 4 
4 5
3 5
%
%
3 4
4 2
```

Here is my code that ignores the lines start with % and write it to the another .su2 file:

> program update_su2_file
>
> ```
>   IMPLICIT NONE
>   INTEGER :: I
>   CHARACTER(80) :: LINE
>
>
>   OPEN(10,FILE='2DCRM.su2',FORM='FORMATTED')
>   OPEN(20,FILE='2DCRM_updated.su2',FORM='FORMATTED')
>
>
>
>   DO 100 WHILE (.TRUE.)
>   READ (10,'(A)',END=999) LINE  !Read line from input file
>
>   IF(LINE(1:1).EQ.'%') GOTO 100 !Skip line starts with %
>   WRITE(20,'(A)') TRIM(LINE)    !Write line to output file   100 END DO   999 CONTINUE 
>
>   CLOSE (10)
>   CLOSE (20)
>
>   END PROGRAM update_su2_file
> ```

Basically I need to write my updated data to the test.su2 file instead of a new file.

I have tried to update my code as below, but as I mentioned above it does not write my data properly.

> program update_su2_file
>
> ```
>   IMPLICIT NONE
>   INTEGER :: I
>   CHARACTER(80) :: LINE
>
>
>   OPEN(10,FILE='test.su2',FORM='FORMATTED')
>
>
>
>   DO 100 WHILE (.TRUE.)
>   READ (10,'(A)',END=999) LINE  !Read line from input file
>
>   IF(LINE(1:1).EQ.'%') GOTO 100 !Skip line starts with %
>   WRITE(10,'(A)') TRIM(LINE)    !Write line to output file   100 END DO   999 CONTINUE 
>
>   CLOSE (10)
>
>   END PROGRAM update_su2_file
> ```

This is the output file which is not correct:

> ```
> %file
> %file
> ```

Comment: Honestly, just copy the new file over the old one. You can call `mv` or `cp` from Fortran.

Comment: I am sorry if it is not clear on my question. I need to remove "%" characters without creating a new file. Because the input file size can be huge and it will take time. @VladimirF

Comment: It is the thing you should do anyway. Just write a new file. Or do it in a text editor and hope that it has some clever algorithm to avoid a new file (IMHO unlikely, but I know very little).

Comment: And if you are worried about how long it takes to create the file, or how large a second temporary file is, you can probably find a way just to ignore those "comment lines" when it comes to processing. For example, if you're reading in to an array and want to use `read(10,*) big_array` then rewrite in terms of appending new rows.

Comment: Even something in-place like `sed -i '/^%/d' test.su2` works by creating a temporary working file.

Comment: @francescalus Where can I use this command in my fortran code?

Comment: The `sed` command there is not a Fortran thing, but just a general text editing utility. Like Vladimir F says, there are often better tools already available than writing text processing jobs in Fortran.

Comment: I know that can be done several ways. But there is an automated process and I am trying to remove the "%" in this process, basically it will be a part of another fortran code.

Answer (score 2):

Editing the file in-place is the wrong way to solve your problem. You should write your desired output to a second file and, if desired, replace the original file with this second.

Rather than showing how to edit the file in place, I'll explain why this isn't what you should be doing.

*A connected external file has a single position.* For this task you need to maintain two positions: where you're about to write, and the read progress you've made so far. You can do this, but you'll have to manually track and reposition.

*Your file has records of differing length.* If you want to replace the first record with content `%file` with the record with content `4 4`, or the content `%` with `2 4` you need to shift the location in the file of anything else that follows. This will dwarf any filesystem access cost that creating a second file has.

Even with just these two issues, it's already become a Herculean task.  One you will get wrong, trashing your only copy of the file. Much easier to write to a second file.

---

You also have to think about reproducibility and usability. For this task your program is idempotent (so won't matter if you run the program again on your new file), but not all similar programs will be.

Just like when testing your dangerous overwriting program, you'll want the original available in the future: tomorrow, your supervisor says "I'd like the input data you got so I can share with my other student", or a journal reviewer asks "What did the original source look like?". You want to keep the original research artifact safely stored away so "in place" makes little sense.

Comment: The other compelling reason for not writing programs to edit files in place is that the first time one runs such a program it wrecks the only copy of the file one has.  One never gets these programs right first time!  No file is so big that one shouldn't have a backup copy of it; if it's too big for one's disks back it up to tape.

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer @francescalus. Lets assume that I proceed with working with two files (one is the original and the other one edited file)  May I ask you that how can I replace  the second file with the original one in fortran?  It is an automated process so it will be great to do this step at the end of the file.

Comment: You can simply (non-portably) ask your operating system to rename files, (perhaps in an abstracted way like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19689502/3157076)). But maybe you don't need to rename, instead referring to the unit of the file you've just created instead of the original?